# Checkbox + label jquery validation

Tags: jquery

How make to work message error in checkbox + label using jquery validation?

I have this code:

html

```
    <form id="myform">
 <input type="checkbox" id="term" name="term_1" /> 
   <label for="term">
      <div class="check"></div>
      Blabla Term.
   </label>
</form>
<a href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank"></a>
```

css

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label .check {
    display:inline-block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    margin:-3px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label .check {background:url(http://www.1.ligapariurilor.ro/imagini/sprite/radio-sprite.png) left top no-repeat;}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label .check{
    background:url(http://www.1.ligapariurilor.ro/imagini/sprite/radio-sprite.png) -16px top no-repeat;
}
```

And jQuery does not work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            'term': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/AsuyC/17/

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: I try to put error message when not checked

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            '#term': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer. That's also a possibility for your issue.
If you work on asp.net you can use the `RequiredFieldValidator` on your different control such as the following example :

```
<tr>
<td>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat=server
    ControlToValidate=txtName
    ErrorMessage="Identifier is required."> *
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
<td>User Identifier :</td>
<td><input type=text runat=server id=txtName></td>
</tr>
```

For the required fields you can use ValidationSummary property which display an " * " before required fields.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat=server
      headerText="there is error on this page/>
```

and don't forget the validation method :

```
public sub OnSubmit(source as Object, e as EventArgs)
    if Page.IsValid then
    ' Some code
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: I use wordpress. Can you show me a demo on my example?

Comment: here you have a great sample : http://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/checkboxlist-validation-using-jquery/